# Javascript: Transform object with arrays into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Please excuse if I am using wrong terms, but I am completely new to this type of technology. Concerning my question:
I have a webapp that returns either

```
 {
    "amount": "1",
    "unit": "59edd0b2b714531cac8afced",
    "part": "59ede77d52023619d45e949a",
    "comment": "comment 1"
}
```

or

```
{
    "amount":["12","24"],
    "unit":["59edd0b2b714531cac8afced","59edd0b7b714531cac8afcee"],
    "part":["59ede77d52023619d45e949a","59fe50ca25811e25cc38446d"],
    "comment":["comment xyz","comment whatever"]
}
```

In both scenarios, I'd like to have an array of objects like below:

```
[
{
    "amount": "12",
    "unit": "59edd0b2b714531cac8afced",
    "part": "59ede77d52023619d45e949a",
    "comment": "comment xyz"
},
{
    "amount": "24",
    "unit": "59edd0b7b714531cac8afcee",
    "part": "59fe50ca25811e25cc38446d",
    "comment": "comment whatever""
}
]
```

Whats the easiest way to achieve this? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not here to do the work for you, only to help with existing attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just build a function that converts it to the format you want, like this:

```js
function convert(data) {
  if (!Array.isArray(data.amount)) {
    return [data];
  }
  var final = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.amount.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var key in data) {
        obj[key] = data[key][i];
    }
    final.push(obj);
  }
  return final;
}

var data = {
    "amount":["12","24"],
    "unit":["59edd0b2b714531cac8afced","59edd0b7b714531cac8afcee"],
    "part":["59ede77d52023619d45e949a","59fe50ca25811e25cc38446d"],
    "comment":["comment xyz","comment whatever"]
}
data = convert(data);
console.log(data);

data = {
  "amount": "1",
  "unit": "59edd0b2b714531cac8afced",
  "part": "59ede77d52023619d45e949a",
  "comment": "comment 1"
}
data = convert(data);
console.log(data);
```

This works on the assumption that if it comes in the array format, each key will contain an array of the same length.